connecting to AWS account with assume role - Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"
From my Jenkins file, I am trying to connect to my aws account using assume role policy. This is the code:
        ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::202533537610:role/terraform-jenkinsrole"
        SESSION_NAME="terraformsession"
            
        # Assume the role
            CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name "$SESSION_NAME")
            
        # Extract and export the credentials
            export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r .Credentials.AccessKeyId)
            export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r .Credentials.SecretAccessKey)
            export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r .Credentials.SessionToken)

The Trust relationship on this role is the following:
      {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
         "Statement": [
      {   
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::202533537610:role/terraform-jenkinsrole"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
   ]
 }

The 2 policies that are attached to this role are:
        Policy 1: AdministratorAccess 
        Policy 2:  
       {
             "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
        {
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
             "Resource": 
              "arn:aws:iam::202533537610:role/terraform-jenkinsrole"
          }
       ]
      }

When I run the jenkins pipeline, I get this error:
++ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::202533537610:role/terraform-jenkinsrole --role-session-name terraformsession
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

This IAM role has Admin access to the ec2 service. Why can't get temporary credentials with the CLI command?
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name "$SESSION_NAME"


To make a call to aws sts assume-role, you require a set of AWS credentials so that AWS knows who you are and can verify that you are permitted to assume the role. This way, you would be permitted to assume the role, but I would not be permitted since I don't have any credentials that are allowed to assume the role.
Given that is says Unable to locate credentials when calling aws sts assume-role, it seems like the AWS CLI is unable to find credentials to use.
If the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, then permissions would normally be supplied by assigning an IAM Role to the EC2 instance. If you are running the code on your own computer, you would need to provide IAM User credentials via a configuration file. You can create the configuration file by using the aws configure command.

John, The Jenkins pipeline code is running on the AWS EC2 instance.  The EC2 instance has been assigned an IAM role which has Admistrator access privileges.

Appreciate the reply. The error is from the Jenkins console output.  Once it reaches this line, it throws the error.   CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name "$SESSION_NAME")

@sutterhome1996 - does aws sts assume-role run successfully from command line (that is, outside of Jenkins)? If it gives Unable to locate credentials, then your instance does not have role attached to it! if it does work (or give some other error, like not authorized then your Jenkins creates some isolated environment that doesn't have access to instance role. Which way is it?

Felix, I appreciate the reply. I ran this command out side of Jenkins from git bash. I got this error   [ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-42 ~]$ CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::202533537610:role/terraform-jenkinsrole" --role-session-name "hello")
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-42 ~]$ It is complaining about security token

From AWS documentation, I understoond that, (please correct me if I am wrong) when we issue this AWS cli command ((aws sts assume-role ), this command gets a temporary credentials using security token service to connect to my aws account right?

Yes. It will use the credentials associated with the IAM Role assigned to the instance to make the AssumeRole call. However, the error suggests that the credentials are invalid. Perhaps you have Environment Variables already assigned from a previous execution and those credentials have now expired? Environment Credentials will be used before an IAM Role. See: AWS CLI Configuration and credentials precedence

This comment from @JohnRotenstein 'Perhaps you have Environment Variables already assigned from a previous execution and those credentials have now expired?' is more likely the culprit. Have you tried using AWS plugin?  Something like this? https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/#plugin-content-withaws
